# Discretize a date-time variable to "in-hours" and "after-hours"

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have date-times like:

```
x = c("2015-09-12 03:52:00", "2017-06-15 21:37:28", "2017-04-08 20:44:11")
```

I want to create two categories: If the time is between 6.30pm and 8 am I want to return "after-hours"`, otherwise it returns "in-hours".

I tried to solve this first by extracting the time part, but that converted it to a character which meant, `ifelse` was not working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### base R

Cheating a little, converting to `%H%M` as an integer on a 24h clock.

```r
vec <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-09-12 03:52:00", "2017-06-15 21:37:28", "2017-04-08 20:44:11"))
hhmm <- as.integer(format(vec, format = "%H%M"))
ifelse(hhmm < 0800 | hhmm > 1830, "after-hours", "in-hours")
# [1] "after-hours" "after-hours" "after-hours"
```

### lubridate

Similar, but using decimal hours instead of fake-hour/minute.

```r
library(lubridate)
hhmm2 <- hour(vec) + minute(vec)/60
ifelse(hhmm2 < 8 | hhmm2 > 18.5, "after-hours", "in-hours")
# [1] "after-hours" "after-hours" "after-hours"
```

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring, big oops typo.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans. Started an R online course now so in the future I should know all this.

Answer (score 0):

```
times_as_char = c("2015-09-12 03:52:00", "2017-06-15 21:37:28", "2017-04-08 20:44:11")

# Converting character to date-time
times_as_datetimes <- lubridate::ymd_hms(times_as_char)

# We can use decimal hours to make time comparisons easier
times_as_hour_dec <- lubridate::hour(times_as_datetimes) + 
 lubridate::minute(times_as_datetimes)/60

time_status <- ifelse(times_as_hour_dec < 8 | times_as_hour_dec >= 18.5, 
                      "after-hours",
                      "in hours")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it. I just ran it and it worked. Thank you.