# Mutate dataframe based on day and night shifts in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My goal is to mutate a dataframe by day and night shifts where a day shift is defined as 6:45-18:45 and a night shift is from 18:45-6:45. My issue is that I cannot manage to segment night shifts correctly as they occur over 2 different dates. My desired outcome is as follows

```
 date        time        shift
    17/08/2018  23:40:00 Night 1
    17/08/2018  23:56:00 Night 1
    18/08/2018  00:33:00 Night 1
    18/08/2018  04:02:00 Night 1
    18/08/2018  08:03:00 Day 1
    18/08/2018  12:25:00 Day 1
    18/08/2018  22:30:00 Night 2
```

However my code produces

```
 date        time        shift
    17/08/2018  23:40:00 Night 1
    17/08/2018  23:56:00 Night 1
    18/08/2018  00:33:00 Night 2
    18/08/2018  04:02:00 Night 2
    18/08/2018  08:03:00 Day 1
    18/08/2018  12:25:00 Day 1
    18/08/2018  22:30:00 Night 2
```

The code I have used is

```
am_shift_start = as.numeric(lubridate::hms("06:45:00"))
am_shift_end = as.numeric(lubridate::hms("18:45:00"))
merged_csv$DATE = as.Date(merged_csv$DATE, format = "%m%d%Y")
merged_csv = merged_csv %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  mutate(shift = if_else((as.numeric(TIME) >= am_shift_end |
                            as.numeric(TIME) <= am_shift_start), "Night shift", "Day_shift")) %>%
  arrange(DATE, TIME)
```

where merged_csv is just the each daily csv of a given month merged into one. I tried to improve on the code naively with a forloop, but the ID counter doesnt work due to the if statement

```
static_id = 1
merged_csv$unique_shift = c(1,rep(-99, length(merged_csv[[1]])-1))
temp_date = merged_csv$DATE[1]
for(i in 2:length(merged_csv[[1]])){
  if(merged_csv$DATE[i] != temp_date){
    temp_date = merged_csv$DATE[i]
  }
#new shift as we are in a day shift or we are starting the next night shift >6:45pm
  if(merged_csv$shift[i] != merged_csv$shift[i-1] | (as.numeric(merged_csv$TIME[i]) > am_shift_end & merged_csv$shift[i] == "Night shift")){
    static_id = static_id + 1
  }
  merged_csv$unique_shift[i] = static_id
}
```

Is there any easier way to go about this (a working method even)? Thanks.

EDIT: adding the example data as a dataframe

```
merged_csv = data.frame(
  "date" =   c("17/08/2018",  "17/08/2018" , "18/08/2018", "18/08/2018",  "18/08/2018", "18/08/2018",  "18/08/2018"),
  "time" = c("23:40:00", "23:56:00", "00:33:00", "04:02:00", "08:03:00", "12:25:00", "22:30:00")
)
merged_csv$date = as.Date(merged_csv$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
merged_csv$time = lubridate::hms(merged_csv$time) #
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/66356952/3358272, I think you can use either of the answers (no `for` loop required).

Comment: can you post some lines from `merged_csv`?

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the link, but I believe my code does exactly that already. I would like to modify it to give me unique day/night shifts.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have added a small dataframe at the bottom that relates to the example given.

Comment: Is 2020 vs 2018 a typo, or is year not a factor in which day number?

Comment: @r2evans it was a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

merged_csv %>%
  mutate(
    shift_i = findInterval(time, hms(c("00:00:00", "08:00:00", "18:30:00", "24:00:01"))),
    shift = paste(if_else(shift_i == 2L, "Day", "Night"),
                  date - min(date) + (shift_i == 3L))
  )
#         date       time shift_i   shift
# 1 2018-08-17 23H 40M 0S       3 Night 1
# 2 2018-08-17 23H 56M 0S       3 Night 1
# 3 2018-08-18     33M 0S       1 Night 1
# 4 2018-08-18   4H 2M 0S       1 Night 1
# 5 2018-08-18   8H 3M 0S       2   Day 1
# 6 2018-08-18 12H 25M 0S       2   Day 1
# 7 2018-08-18 22H 30M 0S       3 Night 2
```

The point is to differentiate the "shifts" into not just day and night, but night-before-midnight and night-after-midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  tidyr::unite(datetime, date, time, sep = ' ') %>%
  arrange(datetime) %>%
  mutate(datetime = dmy_hms(datetime), 
         hour = hour(datetime), 
         mins = minute(datetime),
         shift = case_when(hour == 6 & mins >= 45 |
                                  between(hour, 7, 17) | 
                                  hour == 18 & mins <= 45 ~ 'Day', 
                                  TRUE ~ 'Night'), 
         day = data.table::rleid(shift)) %>%
  group_by(shift) %>%
  transmute(datetime, 
            result = paste(shift, match(day, unique(day)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-shift)

#  datetime            result 
#  <dttm>              <chr>  
#1 2020-08-17 23:40:00 Night 1
#2 2018-08-17 23:56:00 Night 1
#3 2018-08-18 00:33:00 Night 1
#4 2018-08-18 04:02:00 Night 1
#5 2018-08-18 08:03:00 Day 1  
#6 2018-08-18 12:25:00 Day 1  
#7 2018-08-18 22:30:00 Night 2
```

Combine `date` and `time` column, change them to `POSIXct`, extract `hour` and `mins` from it. Define 'day' and 'night' shifts based on required range of time and create an incremental sequence with `match` and `unique`.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("17/08/2020", "17/08/2018", "18/08/2018", 
"18/08/2018", "18/08/2018", "18/08/2018", "18/08/2018"), time = c("23:40:00", 
"23:56:00", "00:33:00", "04:02:00", "08:03:00", "12:25:00", "22:30:00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: I like this, but it would have been preferable to not have to combine date and time. Thanks!